# Sorting list nested in tuples

Tags: list, sorting, python-3.x

I am really trying to solve this, but I am having a hard time. I have a list of tuples with nested lists:

```
l1 = [('cherished', ['family', '4.0', '0.0', 'memory', '6.0', '8.0', 'gift', '0.0', '9.0']), 
('lowered', ['flag', '5.0', '0.0', 'chair', '3.0', '0.0', 'volume', '7.0','3.0']), 
('planted', ['plant', '7.0', '7.0', 'seed', '9.0', '28.0', 'tree', '16.0', '0.0'])]
```

In each nested list I have a string followed by two float number, in the example above `'family', '4.0', '0.0'`. What I need to do is to sort this list by the first float of each - string, float, float - sequence, so that I would have something like:

```
l2 = [('cherished', ['memory', '6.0', '8.0', 'family', '4.0', '0.0', 'gift', '0.0', '9.0']), 
    ('lowered', ['volume', '7.0', '3.0', 'flag', '5.0', '0.0', 'chair', '3.0','0.0']), 
    ('planted', ['tree', '16.0', '0.0', 'seed', '9.0', '28.0', 'plant', '7.0', '7.0'])]
```

I tried zipping the list and them sorting it, using:

```
l2 = []
for k, v in l1:
    new_list = sorted(zip(v[::3], v[1::2], v[1::3]), key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
    flattened = [value for pair in new_list for value in pair]
    new_tuple = (k, flattened)
    l2.append(new_tuple)
```

But the outcome is messed up, for `planted`, for example, I get this:

```
('planted', ['seed', 'seed', '9.0', 'plant', '7.0', '7.0', 'tree', '28.0', '16.0']),
```

I tried diffente things to amend it but do not feel getting any closer. Any tips on how to correct that code to do what I want or on alternative ways to accomplish that? I really appreciate!

Comment: What sort result do you need -- `[gift, 0, 9, family, 4, 0, memory, 6, 8]`?

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer Sorry, deleted the output when was formatting. Corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can basically reduced to sort a flat list of triples

```
[ x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ... ]
```

in reverse order by the values of `y`.

One way to do this is to create an intermediate list of triples, sort it, then flatten the result.  Since you have strings, but want to sort them as numbers, you also have to apply `float()` to the values of `y`.

```
def sorted_triples(L):
    # Transform [a, b, c, d, e, f, ...] into [(a, b, c), (d, e, f), ...]
    triples = [L[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(L), 3)]

    # Sort each triple by float value of second element in reverse order
    triples.sort(key=lambda t: float(t[1]), reverse=True)

    # Flatten list of triples
    return [x for t in triples for x in t]
```

You can apply this to your data as follows:

```
for k, v in l1:
    v[:] = sorted_triples(v)
```